# OS X Server no longer externally available for CalDav after Update from 10.6.8 to 10.11.6

Tags: osx-server, caldav

Weird issue here, after updating my client's OS X Server from 10.6.8 to 10.11.6, I can no longer reach my calendar server externally. My client's router is port forwarding to my server 8443 and 8008 over TCP/UDP, and I've tested those ports and found them to be open. External DNS is resolving to the correct IP, and Port Forwarding is pointing to the server

It all works perfectly internally.

I've heard it could be an Apache problem, but I'm not sure where to start there. I haven't found anything that pops out to me in the logs, but that doesn't mean there isn't something there.

Note:
The whole reason for doing this was to make a smoother transition to a newer server that they purchased, but I need to get them up and running first.

Comment: Did you check on the router if the port-forwarding is bound to a distinctive [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) and hasn't been changed to the new one?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not it, the router does not have any sort of MAC address based port forwarding, and the server in question is the original server so that hasn't changed. Good idea though I didn't think about that!